# css JQuery animate did't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a code like this:

```
distance = screen.width * 0.2;

function moveRight() 
        {
            $("#img1").animate({left: distance, width: '150px'}, 900);
            $("#img22").animate({left: distance, width: '150px'}, 900);
            $("#img33").animate({left: distance, width: '150px'}, 900);
            $("#img44").animate({left: distance, width: '150px'}, 900);
        }
```

and the code above work nicely the image move to right side and expand to 150px simultaneously

and then I want to make the image move inverted to the left side so I change code to this:

```
function moveLeft() 
        {
            $("#img1").animate({left: (distance * -1), width: '150px'}, 900);
            $("#img22").animate({left: (distance * -1), width: '150px'}, 900);
            $("#img33").animate({left: (distance * -1), width: '150px'}, 900);
            $("#img44").animate({left: (distance * -1), width: '150px'}, 900);
        }
```

the moveLeft function did't work nicely, it's ignore the left: (distance * -1) and only run the width: '150px', ok when i remove the width 150px but the left: distance * -1 work nicely and move to left side, but how I can I make it work move to left and at the same time it expand to 150px??

Comment: Can you create fiddle/snippet of your issue here?

Comment: what is fiddle/snippet??

Comment: Put your sample code https://jsfiddle.net/ to play with it

Answer (score 0):

Finally i know the problem the move point was starting with the left corner of the image when move to left need to adjust the moving distance, i realise it when i change to img33 (distance * -3) since my image container ratio was 20:60:20